# Explain difference between internal energy and enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

I read that $U=q+w$ and $H=u+PV$ so aren't $PV$ and $w$ same?
If they are, can't we write $H=q+2w$?
Also,
$dU=$ change in internal energy wrt change in temperature keeping $V$ constant times $dT+$change in internal energy wrt change in volume keeping $T$ constant times $dV$
Here is the second term $=w$?
And,
$dH=$ change in enthalpy wrt change in temperature keeping $P$ constant times $dT+$ change in enthalpy wrt change in pressure keeping $T$ constant times $dP$.
Here is the second term $=PV$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain internal energy and enthalpy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92688/)

Comment: My query is quite different

Comment: For starters, if $U=q+w$, then by the same definition, $PV=-w$. Which definition of $w$ are you using? In physics, commonly the definition $U=q-w$ is used, then we have $PV=w$.

Comment: @FreezingFire The work w is not PV or -PV.  It is equal to the integral of PdV or -PdV, at least for a reversible change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the sign convention you are using, $$\Delta U=q+w$$where, for a reversible expansion or compression, $$w=-\int{PdV}$$So, $$\Delta U=q-\int{PdV}$$and$$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (PV)=q-\int{PdV}+\Delta (PV)$$Integrating by parts, we get$$\Delta H=q+\int{VdP}$$

The quantity $$\int{\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_TdV}$$ is not equal to the work.  In fact, for an ideal gas, this quantity is always equal to zero.  Similarly for $$\int{\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_TdP}$$