# Formulation of the Moist Adiabatic Lapse Rate Equation

Tags: meteorology

In the relationship r = ϵe/p−e: mixing ratio of the mass of water vapour to the mass of dry air.
Question: What is ϵe
For clarification see question [Moist adiabatic lapse rate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743892/moist-adiabatic-lapse-rate)

I know that the ratio equation is a ratio of mass but how do I determine the mass of water vapour involved? Is it a function of temperature, a function of pressure, a function of volume or what?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is the ratio of the molar masses of water and dry air, and $e$ is the water vapor pressure at saturation.